# Cannot invoke initializer

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, rtf

I am getting the following error with trying to load an RTF file into a `UITextView`.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Don't post screen shots. Post your code. You need to drop the last parameter (error) and implement Swift2 (do-try-catch) error handling. BTW fileURL was deprecated iOS9 you should use initWithURL method.

Comment: how do i do this all i am new to swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892434/update-code-to-swift-2