# Update code to swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, rtf

How do i update following code to swift 2 i am new

```
if let rtf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("rtfdoc", withExtension: "rtf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil) {

        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(fileURL: rtf, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
        textView.editable = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this code in *try catch* like below..

```
if let rtf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("rtfdoc", withExtension: "rtf") {
    do {
        let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(fileURL: rtf, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
        textView.editable = false
        print(attributedString)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```